# Android JsonObject vs JsonWriter

Tags: android, json

I need to create a JSON string from my database cursor. I see there are 2 ways to do this using JsonObject and at the end doing toString of it. Or I use JsonWriter and stream it to StringWriter. Which one is better to use and why ?